# Limitar join con where en subquery o where fuera del join, laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Encuentro muchas queries asi en el trabajo:

```
           $rawDocuments = DB::table($this->properties->tableName)
                ->join(
                    $this->contracts->tableName,
                    function ($join) use ($contractId) {
                        $join->on(
                            $this->properties->id,
                            '=',
                            $this->contracts->propertyId
                        )
                            ->where($this->contracts->id, $contractId->toString());
                    }
                )
                ->join(
                    $this->propertyDocuments->tableName,
                    function ($join) {
                        $join->on(
                            $this->properties->id,
                            '=',
                            $this->propertyDocuments->propertyId
                        )
                            ->where($this->propertyDocuments->isVisible, true);
                    }

                )
                ->select(
                    $this->propertyDocuments->allColumns,
                    $this->properties->street,
                    $this->properties->number,
                    $this->properties->block,
                    $this->properties->stair,
                    $this->properties->level,
                    $this->properties->door,
                )->get();
```

Yo siempre hago los joins normal y luego limito resultados con el WHERE fuera del JOIN, me cuesta encontrar información sobre este caso específico, si me aclarais que seria mejor os lo agradeceria.

Ejemplo de como lo haria yo:

```
$rawDocuments = DB::table($this->properties->tableName)
    ->where($this->contracts->id, $contractId->toString())
    ->where($this->propertyDocuments->isVisible, true)
    ->join(
        $this->contracts->tableName,
        $this->properties->id,
        '=',
        $this->contracts->propertyId
    )
    ->join(
        $this->propertyDocuments->tableName,
        $this->properties->id,
        '=',
        $this->propertyDocuments->propertyId
    )
    ->select(
        $this->propertyDocuments->allColumns,
        $this->properties->street,
        $this->properties->number,
        $this->properties->block,
        $this->properties->stair,
        $this->properties->level,
        $this->properties->door,
    )->get();
```

Por otra parte tenemos las tablas de la BDD como clases, por eso están asi los nombres de las columnas.

Muchas grácias.

Answer (score 1):

Para observar las diferencias entre una query y otra, podemos hacer uso del método [`toSql`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_toSql) y obtener la salida en lenguaje SQL:

1. En el siguiente fragmento de código, esta sería la forma en que la condición que estableces en el método `where` se aplica (**para el primer script de tu pregunta**).

   ```
   .................
   INNER JOIN contracts ON properties.id = contracts.property_id 
                        AND contracts.id = _valor_aqui
   .................
   ```

   - Considera que: `_valor_aqui` será un [valor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#advanced-join-clauses) y no una columna en si como se indica en la propia documentación (*en caso de no ser la evaluación indicada entonces sugiero evaluar el uso en este caso del método `on` nuevamente*)
2. En cambio cuando colocas las condiciones a nivel *principal* de la query, el resultado en SQL sería algo como esto (**para el caso de tu segundo script**):

   ```
   .................
   INNER JOIN contracts ON properties.id = contracts.property_id 
   WHERE contracts.id = _valor_aqui
   AND aqui_otra_condicion
   .................
   ```

Como puedes observar en el punto 1 el *join* se va a llevar a cabo evaluando 2 condiciones de forma obligatoria (por eso el operador `AND`) mientras que en la segunda el JOIN se lleva a cabo evaluando solo una condición (*aquella que aparece en el `ON`*)